# Cloudstack 4.4 Failed to start system vm

Tags: vmware, apache-cloudstack

I've stumbled on this issue after installing and configuring cloudstack 4.4.

I'm trying to setup cloudstack wiht VMWARE hypervisor, i've followed all the step from the cloudstack documentation, but I have 2 issues.

1. can not start the System Storage VM it fails?
2. When I add a template or ISO on cloudstack the ISO does not upload?

I will try to explain the configuration I have:

1. cloudstack 4.4 is installed on CentOS 6.5
2. Hypervisor VMware esxi5.5
3. VCenter server
4. Primary storage iSCSI vmfs
5. Secondsry NFS (seperate from cloudstack)

If anyone can help me or point me to what the issue might be I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Wat do you mean by the secondary storage vm fails to start? Does the VM not start at all? Or does it start but the agent does not get to a ready state?

Comment: No Miguel it does not start at all.

Comment: Can you post the logs from cloudstack management  server?

Comment: Miguel, I don't see an option to upload files on Stackoverflow?

Comment: Just post the relevant bit of the logs in your questions

Comment: Or add a link to the complete log file to your question

Comment: 2014-08-19 16:08:44,523 INFO  [c.c.s.r.VmwareStorageProcessor] (DirectAgent-43:ctx-db5df539 192.168.20.11) Executing copyTemplateFromSecondaryToPrimary. secondaryStorage: nfs://192.168.20.43/mnt/secondary/, templatePathAtSecondaryStorage: template/tmpl/1/8/, templateName: routing-8
2014-08-19 16:08:44,523 INFO  [c.c.s.r.VmwareStorageProcessor] (DirectAgent-43:ctx-db5df539 192.168.20.11) Secondary storage mount point: /var/cloudstack/mnt/VM/345050675063.3bea8595
2014-08-19 16:08:44,546 ERROR [c.c.s.r.VmwareStorageProcessor] (DirectAgent-43:ctx-db5df539 192.168.20.11)

Comment: Unable to copy template to primary storage due to exception:Exception: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException

Comment: Message: 
Required parameter datastore is missing

Comment: The error points to a problem in your primary storage. What do you see in Infrastructure -> Primary Storage -> (click on name) -> State? Also try to look for a message earlier in the logs, about the time the primary storage was added.

Comment: the state of primary storage shows as being up, it also shows the volume size of the iSCSI.

Comment: I cannot be sure as I cannot test your setup, but it seems to me like the hypervisor cannot mount the primary storage. I would start by testing that and if that doesn't work, post your problem (with all this info) in cloudstack's users mailing list

Answer (score 0):

On your Management Server, run one of the following cloud-install-sys-tmplt command to retrieve and decompress the system VM template. If your secondary storage mount point is not named **/mnt/secondary**, substitute your own mount point name.

**/usr/lib64/cloud/common/scripts/storage/secondary/cloud-install-sys-tmplt -m /mnt/
secondary -u http://download.cloud.com/templates/burbank/burbank-systemvm-08012012.ova -h vmware -s -F**

When the script has finished, unmount secondary storage and remove the created directory

**umount /mnt/secondary**

**rmdir /mnt/secondary**